# HTML Agility Pack isn't correcting paragraph elements properly

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am having issues with some html file being structured like this:

```
<p>
    ...
<p>
```

Obviously whoever wrote this made a syntax error and was actually meaning to write this:

```
<p>
    ...
</p>
```

I was told HTML Agility Pack automatically fixes this on load but that doesn't seem to be the case here. I also tried adding

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["p"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
```

but that just gave me the result of:

```
<p></p>
    ...
<p></p>
```

which doesn't really do what I want. Is there some method that exists in HTML Agility Pack that automatically closes all p tags before a new one is opened?

EDIT: for the work I'm doing p tags won't ever be nested.

Comment: 'closes all p tags before a new one is opened' so you're saying you cannot nest a paragraph tag, that doesn't make sense `<p><span>My Title</span><p>Why should this be illegal</p></p>` You're best bet would be have it automatically close tags but that won't fix the file

Comment: @johnny5 the specific html I'm working with doesn't ever nest paragraph tags. Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "have it automatically close tags"? Thanks!

Comment: The specific HTML doesn't but HTML agility pack cannot assume that,  I'm not sure of how you will specify to tell HTML agility pack to change its default behavior maybe it has an overridable visitor pattern

Answer (score 0):

The tag `p` has some behavior which can cause some similar issue.

Starting from v1.5.0-beta3, you can disable default behavior of the tag `P` with the property `DisableBehavaiorTagP`

See the release note: https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/releases/tag/v1.5.0-beta3